cargo-install-all.sh: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory (On Windows laptop with WSL)
I am new to Solana and Rust, I took latest from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git
Under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux),
./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh --validator-only .
    

You'd see error:
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory

I suspect error is likely due to Windows-style line endings (\r\n) in the script, which causes issues in a Linux environment like WSL, where Unix-style line endings (\n) are expected.
To fix:
sudo apt install dos2unix
find ./scripts -type f -exec dos2unix {} +
find ./scripts -type f -name "*.sh" -exec sed -i 's/\r$//' {} +
find ./scripts -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r$//' {} +

Nothing fixed it.
